# SharePoint 2013 Send Meeting Invitation

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I am in a need to create a meeting invite, which will be sent to registered users. How can we implement the this? this could be an outlook meeting invite or SharePoint Calendar as an attachment of email.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the out of the box functionality, but there is a 3rd party tool: [SharePoint Calendar E-Mail Extension](http://www.sharepointsapiens.com/blog/invite-attendees-from-sharepoint-calendar/). The SharePoint Calendar E-Mail Extension adds the missing e-mail communication to SharePoint calendars and much more.